# $\sum_{k=2}^{n}{k \choose 2}= \binom {n+1} {3} $

Tags: combinatorics

Help with this excercises :)

Proof that

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}{k \choose 2}=
    \binom {n+1} {3} 
$$

please :)

Comment: Do you realize you haven't asked a question? As written, it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hockey stick identity: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to choose 3 numbers from $\{1,\cdots,n+1\}$, so 
there are $\binom{n+1}{3}$ ways to do this.

If $k+1$ is the largest number chosen, where $2\le k\le n$,

then we have $\binom{k}{2}$ ways to choose the two smallest numbers;$\;\;$so $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{k}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$.

(As Jack D'Aurizio points out, this is a special case of a hockey-stick identity.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}{k \choose 2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k!}{2!(k-2)!}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)!}{2(k-2)!}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}
\frac{k(k-1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)$$
then you can split it and use 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(2n+1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n}{2}(n+1)$$